# Why my Public Visualforce Page URL changes automatically?

Tags: visualforce, leads

I have created a simple page with standard controller as Lead and when i previewed it's URL changed from

> https://XXX.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/FirstPage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1

to

> https://XXX.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/devmode/devConsoleViewStateMetadataReceiver.apexp?sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2FXXX.sandbox.vf.force.com

Here is my VisualForce Page Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" sidebar="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="signup form" />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Create a New formr">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Volunteer Information" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField id="Name" value="{!Lead.Name}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField id="Status" value="{!Lead.Status}"/>                 
                <apex:inputField id="Company" value="{!Lead.Company}" required="true"/> 
                <apex:inputField id="Phone" value="{!Lead.Phone}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField id="Email" value="{!Lead.Email}" required="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In last can anyone please let me know how can i make it public as anybody can access it and login will not be required anymore?

Comment: Did you try creating a site and adding this page there

Comment: No. I just opened the developer page and create a new visualforce page. that's it

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Force.com site and add your visualforce page to list of Enabled Visualforce Pages. To create force.com site you have to go to

> setup-> Sites-> create new site

You can set some visualforce page as `Active Site Home Page`. You can set the same page as well and a profile will be created for the same .

You have to give read and create access for lead object for the newly created profile.